# Determine if Task trigger is running in EmailToApexHandler/Email-To-Salesforce context

Tags: emailtosalesforce

I have a simple trigger that should update account information on certain criteria.

Unfortunately, related contact or account id is not available when task runs in EmailToApexHandler context. It seems that Salesforce runs another job on Task after trigger completes (perhaps they fuzz logic to determine right contact is fairly expensive).

I was thinking to run a future job to reprocess such records later, but what is a good way to determine you are executed from email, not from UI?

Comment: What does the [UserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) class tell you when in the EmailToApexHandler context?

Comment: Will check. In trigger logs I've seen it runs as the user for whom dedicated email address was created.

Comment: Yeah it runs as a user for whom the dedicated email was setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround. Turns out Description field has some information that is enough to determine if the Task was created via email-to-salesforce. Hence you can perform a simple check:

> if ( Task.Description.contains('emailtosalesforce@') ) // doSmth();

Comment: Turns out if you BCC to the E2S address this doesn't work :( Looking for something better.